# Вывести строку посимвольно

Tags: c

Где здесь ошибка ? почему выводится мусор?

```
char num1[80];
    printf("Enter: ");
    gets_s(num1);


while (num1[i] != '0') {
        printf("%c", num1[i++]);

    }
```

Comment: маловато информации. Можно больше кода? с объявлением и заполнением массива

Comment: Cделайте чтобы можно было хотяб скомпилироват, но ошибка тут похоже надо так **num1[i] != '\0'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно из-за того, что вы не с тем символом сверяете конец строки.

Пробуйте такой вариант:

```
while (num1[i] != '\0') {
    printf("%c", num1[i++]);
}
```

Дело в том, что конец строки - нулевой символ. Т.е. символ с кодом `0`.

Можно представить этот символ так:

```
char endSymbol = 0;
```

Или так:

```
char symbol = '\0';
```

А `'0'` - это символ с кодом `48` в кодировке `ASCII`.

(Т.е. `'0' != '\0'`, или `48 != 0`).